Science fiction story about gladiators who are also slaves traveling from planet to planet to fight
I read this book in the '80s. It was a story about gladiators that would travel from planet to planet to fight. So it involves space flight. The main character was a young boy. I think he was a slave. And he was in some sort of gladiator school. One scene that I remember was where he was fighting with another young man who is bigger than him. In order to escape his attacks he dove under a table and his attacker thinking that he would have climbed out the other side dove across the top of the table. However the protagonist did not climb out for the table and stuck his knife up above the table to stab the attacker.
That's all I can remember about it

Possibly the 1972 novel Starbrat by John Moressy?
Some points that match:

I read this book in the '80s.

Originally published in 1972

It was a story about gladiators that would travel from planet to planet to fight. So it involves space flight.

Yes.

The main character was a young boy. I think he was a slave. And he was in some sort of gladiator School.

Del, the MC on his sixteenth birthday, he was kidnapped by a band of Daltrescan slave traders, and sold to a gladiatorial school on Tarquin VII.

The fight scene you've mentioned (involving the table) is here also;

Agarix drove me back against the table with a feint and a sweeping,
neck-high slash. I ducked under and rolled to the far side, and he
made his move, anticipating my emergence with a headlong lunge across
the table to spit me on his blade as I popped up. But I hesitated, and
he slid forward on his own momentum, his head and shoulders skidding
on the wet surface to appear above me over the edge. I thrust upwards,
and the blade seemed to leap with a will of its own, sinking to the
hilt in his hairy throat. He let out one choking, gurgling cry, his
blood spurted over my hands, and then the blade fell from his hand and
he lays still, his big head hanging reversed and open-eyed before me,
his brawny arms hanging limp to brush the floor. The blood seeped over
his face, into his gaping nostrils, and dripped in a slow trickle from
his lank hair.


A good find. I've taken the liberty of adding in the missing quote

Proving that even before the Internet there were poor copy-editors.

Thanks @Valorum.  Appreciate the great edit!

I think it could be starbrat. It seems to match everything. I have ordered the book. After I read it and confirm I will come back and provide answer. Thank you for the help. This is basically been a 30-year quest to find this book. The site has answered 2 30-year-old Quest to find books. Amazing that I got answers in less than 2 days.

The answer is 1972 novel Starbrat by John Moressy. Thank you

@KevinfromMichigan Yes the number of people on here who have great memories, or excellent Google-fu is amazing.
